# How to properly share a directory with an another group member? soft-link / hard-link

Tags: symbolic-link, shared-folders, hard-link

My scenario is simple. I am working with another team members, and I want to share my directory with others. I created a symbolic link of the shared directory in their home directories.

`ln -s ~/workspace /home/anotheruser/workspace`

Then I noticed that all the sub-directories and files in the shared directory are actually hard linked to the original ones. What that means is that if I delete one of the original directories, they will still exist in other users' shared directories.

I think I want some kind of shadow directory where all the files and sub-directories are soft linked.

I've found that command `lndir` exists to create soft links for all the files under the shared directory. Another answer suggests to use `cp -rs`.

I am not sure if this schema is proper approach, and if it is how to achieve the goal.